# How does XML be parsed in hadoop in parallel

Tags: xml, hadoop

If I have a large XML file, and I want to process it in parallel. 'Hadoop in practice' use mahout XMLInputFormat, and I find the `getSplits()` method is not overrided. In other words, it's using TextInputFormat's `getSplits()` method. And how does this method avoid splitting the file in the position of begin-tag and end-tag?

When I have a XML file like this. And two mappers are used to process the XML file in parallel.

```
 <persons>            
   <person>             
     <name>John</name>  
     <age>12</age>
   </person>

   . . . . . . .

   <person>
                      ------- until here as the first FileSplit
     <name>Amy</name>
     <age>14</age>
   </person>

   . . . . . . .

   <person>
     <name>Dan</name>
     <age>12</age>
   </person>
 </persons>          ------- remaining as the second FileSplit
```

When the mapper takes the second FileSplit, it can't recognize the Amy record, because it can't find the begin tag.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure to understand the question.

XMLInputFormat does something very similar to TextInputFormat but rather than splitting on end of line it uses `xmlinput.start` and `xmlinput.end` as delimiters. This class is very naïve and do not parse XML and anything complex, it only does dumb pattern matching to find the record boundaries.

The implementation is kind of [straightforward](https://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/mahout/branches/mahout-0.2/examples/src/main/java/org/apache/mahout/classifier/bayes/XmlInputFormat.java) but you have to really understand what a splits and records are.

A split is a part of a file, defined by a start and a end offset, that will be processed by a mapper. It does **not** need to be exactly aligned with records. It is a coarse grained thing and the `RecordReader` will take care of the "exact offsets". For example, `TextInputFormat` computes the splits based on `mapred.max.split.size`. It does **not actually read** the file. It only does very simple maths based on this variable and the file size (can be a bit more complex than that, because of compression for example, but you get the idea).

A record is the thing that will be passed as a <key, value> to your mapper. A record reader is in charge of extracting the records from a split. It is an easy task, for TextInputFormat it will just look for the next end-of-line characters. XMLinputFormat does some very simple pattern matching.

The only issue to resolve is that the start offset of a split can not be aligned with the start of a record. Same thing for end of split. This is very easily resolved, but a simple algorithm: A record reader skips the bytes after the start offset until it find the first record delimiter and processes the bytes after the end offset until a record delimiter is found.

That's why you don't need to override `getSplits` in XMLInputFormat. The coarse grained split is exactly the same *"please split this file in 10MB parts"*. The fine grained split done by the RecordReader is *"please extract each <person></person> block from this split"*.

To configure XMLInputFormat you have to set the `xmlinput.(start|end)` properties in the configuration.

Comment: The XMLInputFormat just override the `getRecordReader` method, and `getSplits` remains the same as TextInputFormat. "splitting on end of line it uses xmlinput.start and xmlinput.end as delimiters" puzzles me, where does it set the delimiters ?

Comment: Can you point out where (code) the end of the previous and start the next Split is merged or explain how this is handled by explaining the structure of the code so I understand how it works? I stumbled about the same issue, looked in the code and didn't find a handling for this. Is there anywhere a Class-Level Design/Architecture explanation for Hadoop and Spark?

Comment: Ok found it myself. Looked to far.

Comment: Thanks for your explanation! looked to far and it was so close!

Answer (score 0):

Just as addition the code-point.

The Reader doesen't stop reading at the end position if he is in `withinBlock`.

```
private boolean readUntilMatch(byte[] match, boolean withinBlock) throws IOException {
...
                // see if we've passed the stop point:
                if (!withinBlock && i == 0 && fsin.getPos() >= end) {
                    return false;
                }
}
```